# ssh -i Permission denied public key

Tags: linux, ssh

I am trying to SSH as a user on host.

I've created ssh keys using ssh-keygen for user `gitlab` on the host and copied the public key `id_rsa.pub` to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` alongwith copying the private key `id_rsa` to my local machine.

When I try to ssh using the following command:

`ssh -v -i id_rsa gitlab@67.205.XXX.XXX`

I get the following permission denied error:

```
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 67.205.XXX.XXX [67.205.XXX.XXX] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to 67.205.XXX.XXX:22 as 'gitlab'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ERK9s4ZkT4m95jq0sejB38PNAMGaLdIQB98SNqWQDfg
debug1: Host '67.205.XXX.XXX' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/angad/.ssh/known_hosts:46
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/angad/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:/xJTv6gRH+xBW9Q+SnwlkRVada4tMESKT+z1LT2zu18 agent
debug1: Will attempt key: id_rsa  explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/angad/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:/xJTv6gRH+xBW9Q+SnwlkRVada4tMESKT+z1LT2zu18 agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
gitlab@67.205.XXX.XXX: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Not sure how I can debug further.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.

The public_key needs to exists in the `/home/<user>/.ssh/authorized_keys` where `<user>` is the user that generated the ssh-keypair

Comment: What should I do if the `/home/<user>/.ssh` directory is missing? The remote is headless btw.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have id_rsa.pub and id_rsa in the .ssh/ dir of the user which is executing the .ssh command. On the remote host, you have to copy id_rsa.pub as the .ssh/authorized_keys in the home of the user you are ssh'ing on behalf of.